# In PyQt, what is the best way to share data between the main window and a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

I'm in the process of writing my very first GUI application with PyQt4 and I've come upon a question that seems very basic, yet I don't seem to find a good answer:

I'm using a thread to continuously perform a repeated task without blocking the main window. The thread needs some information from the main window (e.g. the current value of a spinbox) that can also change during the runtime of the thread. In this situation, what is the proper way to share such data between the main window and the thread?

Naively, I could come up with the following possibilities:

1. Pass a reference to the host window to the thread and use this to retrieve the current value of the variable in question (see example below).
2. Keep a copy of the variable in the thread and keep it synchronized with the main window by emitting signals whenever it changes.
3. Use global variables.

All three options would most likely work for my particular use case (though 2 would be a bit complicated), but I have a feeling there should be a better/more Pythonic/more Qt-like way.

Here is a minimum working example illustrating what I want to do, in this case using option 1:

```python
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import time, sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.spinbox = QtGui.QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinbox.setValue(1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinbox)
        self.output = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.output)

        self.worker = Worker(self)
        self.connect(self.worker, QtCore.SIGNAL('beep'), self.update)
        self.worker.start()

    def update(self, number):
        self.output.display(number)


class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, host_window):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.host = host_window
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        i = 0
        while self.running:
            i += 1
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('beep'), i)
            sleep_time = self.host.spinbox.value()
            time.sleep(sleep_time)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

PS: Since I'm completely unexperienced with PyQt it's not unlikely that there are other problems with the code or the question is unclear. In this case, please feel free to comment or edit the question.

Comment: Despite my answer, your code seems to work properly, so maybe I'm wrong or there something else I don't get.

Comment: @tmoreau. In this particular case, the worker thread simply accesses the value from the spin-box. If it attempted to *change* the value, that would be much more likely to cause a problem (because it could result in a GUI update). However, calling `value()` is still not thread-safe, because the user could change the spin-box value at the same time, and such changes presumably aren't *atomic* operations. Even so, the worst that could happen would be that the worker thread might get a "stale" value from the spin-box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Widgets are not thread safe, see [Threads and QObjects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html):

> Although QObject is reentrant, the GUI classes, notably QWidget and
>   all its subclasses, are not reentrant. They can only be used from the
>   main thread.

And see more definitions here: [Reentrancy and Thread-Safety](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-reentrancy.html)

---

You should only use widgets in the main thread, and use signal and slots to communicate with other threads.

I don't think a global variable would work, but I honestly don't know why.

---

How to use signals in this example:

```
#in main
self.worker = Worker(self.spinbox.value())
self.worker.beep.connect(self.update)
self.spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.worker.update_value)

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    beep=QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self,sleep_time):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.running = False
        self.sleep_time=sleep_time

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        i = 0
        while self.running:
            i += 1
            self.beep.emit(i)
            time.sleep(self.sleep_time)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def update_value(self,value):
        self.sleep_time=value
```

NB: I use the new style signal and slots

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference. So you're saying option 1 and 3 should not be used. Could you give some hints as to how exactly the desired behavior would be achieved using only signals between the threads? To me this seems an awful complication of a rather basic task (at least when I'm dealing with many different informations that I want to share).

Comment: Well, I feel like using thread is never basic. But I'm still surprised that your code above works perfectly fine, when every documentation I find repeat "do not change/access a widget from anything else than the main thread". Anyway, see the edit for an example with signals.

Comment: Thanks again for the additional example! That doesn't look too bad. :) I would still maintain that keeping two copies of the same information in two places seems strange to me, but this is now what I ended up doing. I also changed the code to keep as much information handling as possible in the main thread, so that I only need to communicate a minimum number of values between the threads.