# PyQt and multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

Going with the common theme: "Qt widgets are not thread safe and should not be accessed from any thread but the main thread".

I have recent experience here, I've done it (because it seemed less complicated than using signals/slots), but the GUI behaves poorly. So now I'm using signals/slots.

My question: What about simply reading settings on the GUI from another thread. For example the state of a checkbox. Is this acceptable?

Comment: It should be ok. The app will not crash, but the value you read can be outdated. See this question's comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081529/in-pyqt-what-is-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-the-main-window-and-a-thread/33082186#comment53984133_33082186

Comment: I suspect that the more complicated the data you are reading, the more likely it is that you'll get nonsense data (not just stale data).

Comment: I've had a play with reading GUI settings from a thread and the GUI does not crash (never did) but still seems to be a bit laggy at random times but not as bad as before when I was manipulating the GUI from a thread. Going by the potential issues raised Ill bite the bullet and use 100% signal/slot. Its not that bad once you get into the mindset. Thanks.

Comment: FYI you can do the reading without signals and slots if you do some tricks with `QApplication.postEvent()`. I have a library called [qtutils](https://bitbucket.org/philipstarkey/qtutils) which uses that `postEvent` to call a specified function (eg any Qt or Python function/method) in the main thread, regardless of the calling thread. See the `inmain` function in the `qtutils/invoke_in_main.py` file.

Comment: The other thing I've noticed, for future readers of this topic, is it's not good to use infinite "while" loops in threads - particularly if they can end up in a state where they are not calling any other functions, using QTimer.singleShot for repeating loops fixed my final ui update problems. this was the final piece of the puzzle to get my ui running smoothly.